# Smoke is not showing with particles Blender

Tags: particles, force-fields

I want to make a turnado. My problem is that I want to add smoke and have the smoke react to the vortex of the turnado, so that it rotates with the turnado. Smoke is not showing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was able to add a smoke, a smoke domain, but it is not rotating with the vortix

Comment: smoke simulation does react to force fields...so what is your problem? i don't get it?

Comment: Play the animation button, and you will not see the smoke, that is the problem

Comment: you added two flow objects but no domain? uhm...ok, you should have written that you are a total beginner of Blender...You will never see any smoke or fluid without a domain. A domain is the "overall world" in which the simulation takes place. I would recommend watching some beginner fluid/smoke simulation tutorials. You always need a domain for that kind of simulation.

Comment: and another hint: you shouldn't make "tornado" simulations if you are beginner. Start with easy (!) tasks and then try more complicated things. Else learning Blender might be a bit frustrating...because simulations are really complicated and changing just one parameter can ruin the whole animation.

Comment: I've added your file to a more conventional download link  without the cached sim. data, so it's small enough

Comment: @Chris,
I added a smock domain, but it is not rotating with the vortex

Comment: @TahaHalabi I'm not the man for that one, sorry.. my knowledge of fluid & smoke sims is very basic indeed :)

Comment: @Chris,
Check the new image in the description, smoke is not rotating with the vertics

Comment: @TahaHalabi: I am sorry, but this is not how this site works. You can ask questions here and you hopefully will get answers. And hopefully other can learn from your question as well. But it is not sense of the site, that you adapt your question every time you get to know the error and adapt it again and again. Because then other won't learn from your question because comments won't be found by search algorithm. But you can ask as many questions as you want here.